# Как удалять буквы и символы в input, кроме цифр?

Tags: javascript, input

```
const keyDownFunc = function(el){
    el.addEventListener('keydown', function (){
        el.value = el.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    });
};
```

В функцию keyDownFunc передается input, в котором после его измененения нужно отсекать буквы и символы. Но первую букву он пропускает, а вторую уже нет. Как сделать чтоб изначально не пропускал вообще никакие буквы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно написал полную ерунду, недавно только начал учиться.

Comment: Попробуй поменять keydown на keyup

Comment: Если вам надо просто не пропускать какие-то символы/буквы/цифры и т.п., то лучше всего слушать событие input

Comment: @АлексейШиманский лучше на `input` :)

Comment: @ΝNL993 да, забыл про него

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, есть `number`:

```html
<input type="number">
```

Ваш вариант:

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('test');
const keyDownFunc = function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
    el.value = el.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  });
};
keyDownFunc(elem);
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text">
```

Если не сильно менять код:

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('test');
const keyDownFunc = function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('input', function() {
    el.value = el.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  });
};
keyDownFunc(elem);
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text">
```

А вообще вариантов много:

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('input', keyDownFunc);

function keyDownFunc() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
};
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text">
```